# ExecCommand justifycenter affect the newline

Tags: javascript

I used the

```
document.execCommand('justifycenter', false).
```

And it worked, it added the new style in the `<p>`.

Just like this `<p style="text-align: center;">blablabla</p>`.

But the new line also had the same style `"text-align: center;"`

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!